# Get back panel from clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

This is my class, I always get a null insted of my panel...

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

```
    [Serializable]
public class DragDropBlock : Panel
{
    public DragDropBlock()
        {
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Down);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Up);
        }

        void Mouse_Down(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {

           Clipboard.SetData("DragDropBlock", this);
        }

        void Mouse_Up(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            IDataObject IBlock = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            DragDropBlock Block = (DragDropBlock)IBlock.GetData(typeof(DragDropBlock));

        }
}
```

Comment: I believe `Mouse_Up` should contain `DragDropBlock Block = (DragDropBlock)Clipboard.GetData("DragDropBlock");`

Comment: Does not work but thanks for the idea!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a class:

```
[Serializable]
class Test
{
    public string Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This works:

```
Test t = new Test()
{
     Data = "DERP!"
};

Clipboard.SetData("Test", t);

Test newT = (Test)Clipboard.GetData("Test");

Console.WriteLine(newT.Data);
```

And if you want to use data objects:

```
Test t = new Test()
{
    Data = "DERP!"
};

Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject("Test", t));

Test newT = (Test)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData("Test");

Console.WriteLine(newT.Data);
```

The output to both of those is:

`DERP!`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correction of my class: Working!!!

```
         [Serializable]
class DragBlock
{
    public string Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DragDropBlock : Panel
{
    DragBlock Block;

    public DragDropBlock()
        {
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Down);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Mouse_Up);

            Block = new DragBlock()
            {
                Data = "TEST!"
            };
        }

        void Mouse_Down(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(new DataObject("DragBlock", Block));
        }

        void Mouse_Up(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DragBlock newBlock = (DragBlock)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData("DragBlock");

            Console.WriteLine(newBlock.Data);
    }
}
```